# R -Finding the columns with only one non-missing value and filling its missing values with that unique non-missing value

Tags: r, missing-data, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains missing data (NA). I want to find the columns that have only one non-missing value and then fill those column with that value. For instance, if my original data set is like this:

```
  df = data.frame(A=c(1,2,NA,NA,1), B=c(NA,NA,3,3,3), C=c(2,5,6,3,6), D = c(NA,1, NA,1,1))

   A  B C  D
1  1 NA 2 NA
2  2 NA 5  1
3 NA  3 6 NA
4 NA  3 3  1
5  1  3 6  1
```

I want to attain:

```
   A  B C  D
1  1  3 2  1
2  2  3 5  1
3 NA  3 6  1
4 NA  3 3  1
5  1  3 6  1
```

I first created this function to do what I want: (please let me know if you have a better option to this)

```
fill_NAs <- function(x){
  x %>% fill(., .direction = "up") %>%
        fill(., .direction = "down")
}
```

And then I tried using mutate_at or mutate_if functions but I couldn't manage to make it work. Some of my attempts were the following:

1)

```
df= df %>% mutate_if ( ~ length(unique(na.omit(.)))==1, ~ fill_NAs(.))
```

I got this error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: no applicable
>   method for 'fill_' applied to an object of class "c('double',
>   'numeric')"

.

2)

```
df_PMM_imp = df_PMM_imp %>% mutate_at(.,names(select_if(.,length(unique(na.omit(.)))==1)), ~ fill_NAs(.))
```

I got this error:

> Error in tbl_if_vars(.tbl, .predicate, caller_env(),
>   .include_group_vars = TRUE) :    length(.p) == length(tibble_vars) is
>   not TRUE

In general I can't seem to understand the logic of mutate_if or mutate_at, I always run into such problems. So my questions are:

1) What is the correct syntax which achieves what I want?
2) Why do I get these errors above, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't fully understood what you want to replace your NAs with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over your columns, check the length of the unique elements that are not `NA` and replace the `NA`s in a column if it contains only a single unique element.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  y <- unique(na.omit(x))
  if(length(y) == 1) {
    x <- y
  } else x
})
```

Result

```
df
   A B C D
1  1 3 2 1
2  2 3 5 1
3 NA 3 6 1
4 NA 3 3 1
5  1 3 6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Elif Cansu Akoğuz,

You can achieve your goal fairly easy by using a `for()`-loop to iterate over your dataframe and than check per column if it meets your requirements:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if (any(is.na(unique(df[i]))) == TRUE & nrow(unique(df[i])) == 2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

With the statement `any(is.na(unique(df[i])))` you check if there is a `NA` somewhere in the column, and with `nrow(unique(df[i])) == 2` you check if the column only consists of two unique values. So if a column meets both statements, you know it consists of 2 values, of which one in `NA`.

Next, you want to replace all values in the column by the value that is not `NA`. To do this you can use `na.omit()` to throw out the `NA` value, and than repeat the remaining value for however long the dataframe is.
A problem is that this will return a list-format, so you will have to use the `unlist()`-function to solve this.

The entire loop will end up looking like this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if (any(is.na(unique(df[i]))) == TRUE & nrow(unique(df[i])) == 2) {
        df[i] <- unlist(rep(na.omit(unique(df[i])), nrow(df)))
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ case_when(
    n_distinct(.[na.omit(.)]) == 1 ~ first(na.omit(.)),
    TRUE ~ .
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
   A B C D
1  1 3 2 1
2  2 3 5 1
3 NA 3 6 1
4 NA 3 3 1
5  1 3 6 1
```